# How do I append new functions and update existing functions in a .R file without duplicating

Tags: r, tidyverse

In my R project folder I have an R script where I create custom functions. I then use the `dump()` function to add those functions to a separate script. For example if I have 2 functions, here is the code I'll use to add them to a separate file called `list_of_functions.R` -

```
dump(c("function_1", "function_2"), 
    append = TRUE,
    file = "list_of_functions.R")
```

The issue I have is that when I create a new function, say `function_3` or make edits to `function_1` or `function_2`, when I run `dump()` again, it duplicates existing functions in `list_of_functions.R`. Is there away to append new functions and just update existing functions without duplicating them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the argument `append = FALSE` will overwrite the existing file, rather than append to it.

See [code reference](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dump) for a detailed explanation.